# Correlating logs with a pattern in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a wrapper script calling actual script & have 2 log files corresponding to it & i need a way to correlate them and show them in a single splunk search for failed run.

For example, I have a log called wrapper__22238.log inside which i have Status message along with a runID which will be the keyword to correlate with child log : worker.log

Sample wrapper_JOB1_22238.log :

```
2021-05-25 05:19:59.817 INFO : Got response: Job: JOB1, runID: 1001-751b81bf-9d79-4283-b700-74e0c10c472a, Timeout: 7199, Request Time: 2021-05-25 04:19:03.333, Start Time: 2021-05-25 04:19:04.726, Status: RUNTIME_ERROR, Total Time: 3645869 ms
```

worker.log :

```
[Date=25/May/2021 04:19:06] [THREAD=61] [runID=1001-751b81bf-9d79-4283-b700-74e0c10c472a] [STEP=Write to Target] [status=ERROR] [Error copying the file to the destination /app/logis/internal/: /app/logis/internal/carrier_1456.out.gz (No such file or directory)]
```

Is there someway to retrieve both logs by just searching based on Job Name(JOB1 above) ?
Assuming I will always have `runID:` in the wrapper status call and worker log will have that tagged in every transaction.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below SubQuery approach helped in my case :

```
(index=foo source=*worker* [search index=foo source=wrapper_JOB1*  | stats max(runID) as runID] status=ERROR)
OR 
(index=foo source=wrapper_JOB1*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do that.  Perhaps more than one, but here's one.

```
(index=foo source=wrapper_JOB1_22238.log Job=bar) OR (index=baz source=worker.log)
| stats values(*) as * by runID
```

It reads events from both logs, filtering wrapper events by Job. Then it combines the events based on their shared runID value.

Comment: Thanks RichG, this helped however due to large number of events in worker.log, this is taking a performance hit.